# Collapsing three columns with bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, tabs

I am trying to make three tabs with cross-referencing with one tab visible at the time. I was using the bootstrap v4 collapse scheme with functionality supported by jQuery. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/omjvhurd/30/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#Tab2_t1").click(function() {
  $('#t1').collapse('hide');
  $('#t1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#t2').collapse('show');
  });
 })
  
  $("#Tab3_t1").click(function() {
  $('#t1').collapse('hide');
  $('#t1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#t3').collapse('show');
  });
 })
  
  $("#Tab1_t2").click(function() {
  $('#t2').collapse('hide');
  $('#t2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#t1').collapse('show');
  });
 })
  
  $("#Tab3_t2").click(function() {
  $('#t2').collapse('hide');
  $('#t2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#t3').collapse('show');
  });
 })
  
  $("#Tab1_t3").click(function() {
  $('#t3').collapse('hide');
  $('#t3').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#t1').collapse('show');
  });
 })
  
  $("#Tab2_t3").click(function() {
  $('#t3').collapse('hide');
  $('#t3').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('#t2').collapse('show');
  });
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 collapse show" id="t1">
      <a href="#" role="button" id="Tab2_t1">Tab 2</a>
      <a href="#" role="button" id="Tab3_t1">Tab 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9 collapse" id="t2">
      <a href="#" role="button" id="Tab1_t2">Tab 1</a>
      <a href="#" role="button" id="Tab3_t2">Tab 3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9 collapse" id="t3">
      <a href="#" role="button" id="Tab1_t3">Tab 1</a>
      <a href="#" role="button" id="Tab2_t3">Tab 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click Tab 2, Tab 1 and then Tab 3, I see two tabs displayed simultaneously. Any idea where the error comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide `.collapse` and show the tab id on your click functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#Tab2_t1").click(function() {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $('#t2').collapse('show');
    })

  $("#Tab3_t1").click(function() {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $('#t3').collapse('show');
    })

  $("#Tab1_t2").click(function() {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $('#t1').collapse('show');
    })

  $("#Tab3_t2").click(function() {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $('#t3').collapse('show');
    })

  $("#Tab1_t3").click(function() {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $('#t1').collapse('show');
    })

  $("#Tab2_t3").click(function() {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $('#t2').collapse('show');
    })
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Maro94/cr6d9L03/3/

Comment: Thank you Maro! While it works as intended it does not have the effect of rolling up the tab before displaying a new one. Point being that in my case I would like to keep the impression that the tabs roll-up and down on click.

Comment: Oh ok. I've made a fiddle for you: [https://jsfiddle.net/Maro94/cr6d9L03/28/](https://jsfiddle.net/Maro94/cr6d9L03/28/). The problem with your code is that when you call the `collapse('show')` on a tab you don't hide it back. Hope I have helped you :)